# Insert or erase character on field without erase previous content

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

There some function in `AcessibilityService` where can insert character on field, but without erase previous content as well simulate backspace button?

by now i'm make it with a global `String` variable eg:

- `text += "My text or character here` - Insertion
- `text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1)` - Backspace

This isn't good because when jump to next field is necessary clear the variable before.

Comment: Before processing anything, first get whatever is in the field. And then you can add to that text and remove character as well. If while getting the field is empty starting with empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a how could be a implementation after suggestion presented by @Pawan Singh Harariya.

**PS:** Tested in *Youtube* and *Google Chrome*.

```
public void keyboardText(String text) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    AccessibilityNodeInfo node = findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT);

    if (node != null) {
        String nodeHint = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            nodeHint = String.valueOf(node.getHintText());
        }

        String nodeText = String.valueOf(node.getText());

        if (nodeHint != null) {
            if (text.equals("BACKSPACE"))
                nodeText = nodeText.substring(0, nodeText.length() - 1).replace(nodeHint, "");
            else if (text.equals("SPACE"))
                nodeText = nodeText.replace(nodeHint, "") + " ";
            else nodeText = nodeText.replace(nodeHint, "") + text;
        } else {
            if (text.equals("BACKSPACE"))
                nodeText = nodeText.substring(0, nodeText.length() - 1);
            else if (text.equals("SPACE"))
                nodeText += " ";
            else nodeText += text;
        }

        arguments.putString(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, nodeText);
        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
    }
}
```